# DynamoDB Keys - One high cardinality one low cardinality?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am creating a new table in DynamoDB, and I am new to its use. I would like some help from anyone who is well informed around query time performance in Dyanamo.

I need to achieve two simple things:

1. Fast query time performance for a single look up, off of a simple, unique and high cardinality ID.
2. Fast query time performance to get ALL things which match `groupId`. This will often be tens of thousands of items and speed of retrieving them in bulk is priority.

Comment: *"This will often be tens of thousands of items"* ...does not sound like an appropriate use case for DynamoDB.

Comment: @mhsc - For requirement 2, if I understand correctly, *tens of thousands of items* will have the same `groupId`, and you need to retrieve all of them together, is that correct? If so, how big are those items, usually? Also, in that specific operation, how much data from each item do you actually need? (ie, if the item is, say, 25kB large in 15 fields, but you are only actually going to use 100 bytes in 2 fields, I'm asking about that "100 bytes"). This will help understand the use case.

Comment: @BrunoReis each row is about 1kb and every field is required. The data is used to train a model.

Comment: DynamoDB is really fast. If you have 10,000 items, each one about 1kb, the biggest bottleneck will be the time it takes to send all the data across the network. That being said, can you be more specific with your question? What exactly do you want help with? Table structure? Queries?

Answer (score 1):

Late to this party, but you should not use the `scan` (because it will be expensive) and instead use a secondary index. More information is available from aws:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html

Answer (score 0):

You use your group_id as partition key and your unique id as secondary key.

Ypou can than use query on partition key to get all items with one group id. A query of group_id AND id will return your single item